# Magento 2.4.3-p3 issue for access Media Gallery

Tags: magento2.4

We facing an issue with the Media Gallery access difficulty, it's already synced by using the command line and all images are there.

```
bin/magento media-gallery:sync
```

Most of the first time is not able to access (or just waiting for the page response until error 524) also this issue happened on the return dashboard after flushing the Magento cache from the admin panel. I am using CloudFlare CDN, is that a problem? or sessionmanager problem?

1. Media Gallery access without issues, unless stops loading and refreshing the page.
2. Flushing the cache of Magento via the Admin panel and returning to the dashboard getting an error about 524 if we did not stop loading the page and refresh again.

Bottom line:

We need to refresh the page before getting an error message is possible to access there, otherwise, we also need to refresh until the error.

Best Regards,